# Kio estas la diferencon inter la vortoj traduki kaj tradraŝi?

Tags: translation

Ĉu ekzistas diferenco inter la du vortoj aŭ ĉu mi povas uzi ĉu unu? Is there a difference between the two words or can I use either one?

Comment: Kie vi renkontiĝis "tradraŝi" kaj kio igis vin pensi, ke ĝi signifas similan aŭ saman kiel "traduki"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a translation of *translate* then *traduki* is the word you want. It is a very common word.

I’ve never heard of *tradraŝi* and it doesn’t appear in [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) or [PIV](http://vortaro.net). In the [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com/?s=5e6805f1d3ada) all of the hits seem to have a very different meaning. This makes me think it is a combination of *tra* + [*draŝi*](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/drasx.html). In that case the two words seem to have completely unrelated meanings so you can’t use them interchangebly. I doubt that *tradraŝi* would be widely understood.

Comment: It is tra+draŝi. It's the word of the day on wiktionary. The link in my other comment below this is the Esperanto wiktionary page about it. Google translate gives 'translate' for both words.

Answer (score 1):

traduk/i = to translate

draŝ/i = to thresh

If you want to talk about translating, only the first word is correct.

Comment: mi pensis tiel, sed tradraŝi estas la vorto de la tago en Esperanto wiktionary https://eo.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tradra%C5%9Di

google translate tradukas ambaŭ "traduki" kaj "tradraŝi" kiel "translate"

Comment: @jastako En la paĝo, al kiu vi ligas, mi klare vidas “thrash” kiel unu el la tradukoj al la angla (“translate” ne aperas). Krome, la signifo en Esperanto estas skribita jene: “(figure) forte trabategi”; kaj estas skribite, ke la vorto kreiĝas kiel “tra + draŝ + i”, do mi vere ne kompronas, kiel estiĝis via konfuzo :p.

Comment: Google translate ne estas fidebla fonto por traduki unuopajn vortojn. Verŝajne ĝi tute ne konas la vorton *tradraŝi* kaj anstataŭ agnoski ke ĝi ne scias la vorton ĝi simple serĉas vorton kiu plej proksimas al konata vorto.

Comment: Mi scias la vorton "traduki" sed mi uzis glosbe por serĉi draŝi kaj tradraŝi kaj ne akiris rezulton per ambaŭ. Mi ne uzas Google por unuopaj vortoj krom se mi ne povas trovi ĝin aliloke. Kio retsitio vi rekomendas anstataŭ google translate?

Comment: Mi estas komencanto, do mi ne multe komprenis.

Comment: re _'tradraŝi estas la vorto de la tago en Esperanto wiktionary eo.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tradra%C5%9Di google translate tradukas ambaŭ "traduki" kaj "tradraŝi" kiel "translate"'_: @jastako you may want to edit that into your question, so it has some context.